# Zend Mail sending with headers shown in body and header section in mail clients

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend Framework to send mail.

It's doing something very odd, the content type, content dispostion, MIME version and content type encoding are all showing up in the header section (under the subject) of the email in GMail and in Outlook.

The content of the email was also being included twice in the email, once as plain text and once as HTML. I stopped this by just using setBodyText() instead of using setBodyHtml() too. I had seen somewhere that you can use both. Now I just use setBodyText() like this

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
$mail->addTo("mail@mail.com");
$mail->setSubject("Registration info");
$mail->setFrom('do-not-reply@mail.com', "A Name");
$mail->setBodyText($this->view->render('emails/register.phtml'));
$mail->send();
```

Comment: Is this happening because I'm using 'utf-8'? Maybe I could be leaving it blank to send as HTML?

Comment: I've now established that setting it to utf-8 or html makes no difference. The contents of the email is still broken. It works fine from my local machine, but not from my live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved. It was an error with the host receiving the email. The fact it was in Outlook or GMail made no difference as the error was with the host.

Comment: What was the problem with the host?